# PowerShell Static Methods; "Missing '(' in class method parameter list"

Tags: powershell, oop, static, hashtable

```
class HostDataRetriever {

static [hashtable] Get-HostData() {
    [string]$OS = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Name
    [string]$IP = Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object { ($_.InterfaceAlias -eq "Ethernet") -and ($_.AddressState -eq "Preferred") } | Select-Object IPv4Address
    [array]$Software = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object name
    return @{
        "name" = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        "OS" = $OS
        "IP" = $IP
        "Software" = $Software
    }
}
```

}

Hi,
I don't get what i'm doing wrong syntactically; i get 3 Errors:

- "Missing '(' in class method parameter list"
- "Missing function body in function declaration"
- Unexpected token '}' in expression  or statement

Comment: `Get-HostData` is a name you would put to a function not to a method :) this is probably a parser error due to the hyphen

Comment: Oh.. i got it. That seems to have done the trick.. PowerShell is weeird :D Thanks!

Comment: It is, but is also awesome ;)